# Why can't I read csv file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

I read some other threads here at stack and one of them is that you don't need to install  csv, but when I import csv module, `"from cvs import *"` is grey coloured.

When you import it in your code it should go gray until used, that's how PyCharm distinguishes between used and unused modules by default.

So how can I solve this?

```
from csv import *

excel_file = open(”dataset_Facebook.csv”, r)

excel_file.close()
```

This is traceback I get:

```
/Users/Melina/Deskop/mmmmm/venv/bin/python /Users/Melina/Deskop/mmmmm/test.py
  File "/Users/Melina/Deskop/mmmmm/test.py", line 3
    excel_file = open(”dataset_Facebook.csv”, r)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And in my terminal

```
Last login: Mon Jan 14 11:54:57 on ttys000
melinas-MacBook-Pro:~ Melina$ pip install python-csv
Collecting csv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for csv
melinas-MacBook-Pro:~ Melina$
```

I Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0 demjson-2.2.4 jtutils-0.0.6 leven-1.0.4 python-csv-0.0.11 xmltodict-0.11.0

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix mistakes in your code.

First, don't import everything in your script. There are other ways to import, but you can use `import csv`.

Also, strings should be in **" "** or in **' '**, not in **” ”**.

And lastly, mode should be string *'r'*, not just **r** because then it represent variable.

I won't go into details about using csv module, there is a great article at [real python](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) but here is basic example:

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:  # mode is by default 'r' for read.
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Cheers !